# How to measure the force produced by a finger?

Tags: forces

If I push my finger onto a weighing balance and it reads 100g, then how do I calculate the force produced by my finger? Do I just use F = mg? Or is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You are correct. A balance actually measures force, but the readout is conveniently scaled to tell you how many grams of mass would feel that same force from gravity near the surface of the Earth.

All you have to do is reverse that scaling to get the force in Newtons.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand... Reverse the scaling? Can you show an example?

Comment: @Justin, you've already given it: $F=mg$, where $m$ is the mass value that you get from the balance, and $g$ is the [acceleration due to Earth's gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_acceleration) in the location where your balance was calibrated\*, and $F$ is the unknown force. (\* Unless we are talking about a lab balance costing tens of thousands of dollars, and you need to know the force with many digits of precision, then you can probably just say $g=9.81\text{m/s}$ and call it good.)

Comment: Ahhh... yes, understood. Thank youu!